# Access control for announcement users to view via link

Tags: 7, users

Is there a module available or anyone have a hint as to how one could create private links? I have a site that is locked down via access control, but I would like to send an announcement user a link to be able to view that piece of content.

Sort of like a Dropbox share. I can elaborate more on my use case if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by an "announcement user"? Is that a registered user with an account to login to your site? Also: "to send" such link, is it correct to assume that would be via eMail? And if so, what kind of information do you have available (and how is it implemented) to know what the eMail ID to use would be?

Comment: Sorry Typo "anonymous user"

Comment: OK, that helps. But can you also answer my last question (how do you know the eMail ID to use)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Node authorize link](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_authlink).

> Generates link for view, edit, or delete content without login.
>
> Module maintains authorization key for every node and gives additional
>   grants (view/edit/delete) to every user (anonymous too) who accesses
>   page with correct key in URL. Module offers function
>   node_authlink_get_url($node, $op = 'view') for generate absolute URL
>   to selected operation (e.g. for e-mail notifications).

Although the module is minimally maintained I used it two years ago and I did the work.

You can generate links that an anonymous user can use to get access to view a node, for example. I think it works with Conent Access, but not I'm not sure. May be you have to tweak precedence.